# Integral to get the derivative of the gamma function

Tags: measure-theory, integration

To prove that the gamma function is differentiable (through differentiation under the integral) I need to show that for all $\beta \in (0,1)$ the function

$\displaystyle \frac{e^{-x}\log(x)}{x^\beta}$ is Lebesgue integrable over $(0,\infty)$

I showed it for $\beta=1$ and wanted to try using the same method:

Using the Taylor expansion of $\log(1-x)$, then integrate each term and compare it to the converging series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ , do you think something like that is possible for smaller $\beta$ as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x \to 0$ we have

$$
\frac{e^{-x}\log x}{x^\beta} \sim \frac{\log x}{x^\beta},
$$

and $\int_0^\delta \log x / x^\beta\,dx$ can be shown to converge by integrating by parts.  To see that the integral converges near $x=\infty$ you could note that

$$
\frac{e^{-x}\log x}{x^\beta} \leq e^{-x}\log x
$$

for $x \geq 1$, and

$$
\log x \leq x
$$

by concavity, so that

$$
\frac{e^{-x}\log x}{x^\beta} \leq x e^{-x}
$$

for $x \geq 1$.  As before, the convergence of $\int_{\delta}^{\infty} x e^{-x}\,dx$ can be shown using integration by parts.